# How to edit on BGA/PGA DECAL?

Tags: pcb, bga

I want to ask you about this please how I can edit Component DECAL already placed on PCB file ? the idea is I found that some chips may be the same but different pin numbers like if BGA has 160 pins I want to make it 200 and save it ! 
like this
[image]

is there a way to create and import my new DECAL to the PCB PADS ? please help me

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the number of pins, you need to do that from the library (File->Library), for other changes (Solder mask, silk, pin shape, things like that) you can do it from within layout (Select the part, right click, edit decal), you will be offered the choice of changing just the single instance or every on your board instance.

Note that doing it within the layout will not normally update the library copy.